# Passing a parameter to Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action method like this

```
public JsonResult Create(Product p, string extra)
```

The view is bound to `@model Product`

On calling Create action via ajax call, I am getting Product P values from the form but extra is always null, although extra is in the same form

```
<input type="text" name="extra" />
```

I also tried Request.Form["extra"] it was null too. What I am missing? how to get value of input[name=extra] in action method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention how are you calling this action (other than saying AJAX which obviously is not enough), so assuming you have an HTML form representing a product and an input field containing some extra value:

```
@model Product
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <input type="text" name="extra" value="some extra value" />

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

you could unobtrusively AJAXify this form like this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            // TODO: handle the results of the AJAX call
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @coure06, great, then there shouldn't be any problem as I've just tested it and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: THANKS... YOU ARE ALWAYS HELPFUL. CAN YOU PLZ RECOMMEND SOME GOOD BOOK FOR ASP.NET MVC FOR ME?

Comment: @coure06, [Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework](http://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-Framework-Experts-Voice-NET/dp/1430228865) is a good book. And soon will be released the [Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Framework/dp/1430234040) from the same author.